# Azure Machine Learning Compute Instance Not Creating using Azure CLI and Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: yaml, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, azure-machine-learning-service

I create my Azure Machine Learning Workspace using Azure CLI:

```
$env="prd"
$instance="001"
$location="uksouth"
$suffix="predict-$env-$location-$instance"

$rg="rg-$suffix"
$ws="mlw-$suffix"
$computeinstance="vm-$suffix".Replace('-','')
$computeinstance
az group create --name $rg --location $location
az configure --defaults group=$rg
az ml workspace create --name $ws
az configure --defaults workspace=$ws
az ml compute create --name $computeinstance --size Standard_DS11_v2 --type ComputeInstance
```

I run the above code manually in Visual Studio Code, and everything works properly.

However, when I integrate the above into an Azure DevOps pipeline via the YAML:

```
steps:
 - bash: az extension add -n ml
    displayName: 'Install Azure ml extension'
 - task: AzureCLI@2
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: "$(AZURE_RM_SVC_CONNECTION)"
      scriptType: 'ps'
      scriptLocation: 'scriptPath'
      scriptPath: './environment_setup/aml-cli.ps1'
```

- The pipeline creates the Azure Machine Learning workspace as expected.
- The pipeline creates the compute instance, which has the status **"Running"** and green status.
- However, the compute instance has all applications **greyed out**. This means I cannot connect to the compute instance using a terminal, notebook or otherwise, essentially making it useless. The application links in the following screenshot are not clickable:

[image]

I attempted:

- Specifying brand new resource names.
- Creating the workspace and compute in separate pipelines in case of a timing issue.
- Deleting the resource group first using:

```
az group delete -n rg-predict-prd-uksouth-001 --force-deletion-types Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines --yes
```

All to no avail.

How do I create a useable Azure Machine Learning compute instance using Azure CLI and Azure DevOps pipelines?

Answer (score 0):

Earlier only the creator of the instance was allowed to run the jupyter,jupyterlab etc([check the comments on this issue)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/51855) but now there is a [feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-manage-compute-instance?tabs=python#create-on-behalf-of-preview) in preview that allows to create a compute instance "on behalf of" someone.

[image]

So please try passing the aad user's objectid who will access the compute instance's development tools. The same can be done using arm templates also using 'personalComputeInstanceSettings' property.

> az ml compute create --name $computeinstance --size Standard_DS11_v2
> --type ComputeInstance --user-object-id <aaduserobjectid> --user-tenant-id <aaduserobjecttenantid>

[image]